# How to use allocator to change vector values?

Tags: c++

I want to use std::allocator to change vector values, but i cant understand why when i construct a vector with this allocator as an argument to constructor, the afterward manipulation with this allocator do not change the vector contents.

To be more specific, consider simple example:

```
allocator<int> alloc;
vector<int> iVec(alloc);

int* pAlloc = alloc.allocate(1);
int i = 123;
alloc.construct(pAlloc, i);
cout << pAlloc[0] << endl; // this outs '123'
cout << iVec[0] << endl; // this causes out of range error. why?
```

Any advice what i have missed would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: It's really unclear and confusing what you are trying to do. Why do you think that `int* pAlloc = alloc.allocate(1);` would modify the contents of the vector?

Comment: You should just `iVec.push_back(1)` and let the internals of `std::vector` use your allocator as appropriate.

Comment: _"...Allocator - An allocator that is used [by `std::vector`] to acquire/release memory  and to construct/destroy the elements in that memory...."_ source - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: because when i've studied implementation of a vector from Accelerated C++ book, there was a push_back() redefenition that just used construct() to add elements, so i assumed that i can use it in similar way with std::vector.

Comment: @hgrev I'm 99.9% sure that the `push_back` function there did more than just call `construct`. Which is exactly why your code snippet doesn't make any sense

Comment: You've misunderstood how `alloc` is used by `std::vector`. You cannot manipulate a `std::vector` by manipulating its allocator. You created storage for a single `int` then constructed it with an initial value. There is no relation at all between `pAlloc` and `iVec`.

Comment: but even std::vector uses construct() inside its realization of push_back(). isn't that mean that vector is operating its allocator to add values?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. It uses the allocator in order to allocate memory and construct objects in the allocated memory. The rest of the "adding values" functionality is still part of the `std::vector` and not its allocator. The allocator has no special information about what the vector is doing with the memory it requested

Comment: i tried to get this information in several books and by analysing std code. thanks for this. so can you just explain a little what is that "rest" functionality that is adding values ? can i use it directly without push_back?

Comment: A `std::vector` has at least 3 things it needs to keep track of - the array it owns, the number of items (size) and the maximum amount of items before it needs to reallocate the array (capacity). So adding a new item can potentially modify all 3 of those. It's still unclear to me what exactly you are hoping to achive by "use it directly without `push_back`" and any attempts to do are very likely to just break a lot of things

Comment: i just don't understand the semantics of allocators if they cant be used to add a element to vector. they seem to be 'useless' if they 'add' an element to memory using construct() but container with this allocator doesnt change. it seems absurd to me. maybe the problem is that vector size should be increased before calling construct() (this check exists in both book realisation of vector and in std realization)? but this process of adding the size of vector is made with the same allocator, just using reallocate

Comment: The vector calls `Allocator::allocate` on the instance it has when it needs an allocation. You don't have access to that instance (it is a private sub-object of the vector), and you don't need access to it (especially if `Allocator::is_always_equal` is `std::true_type`)

Comment: so that practically means that 1. i can only use push_back() to add elements to std::vector and 2. allocator that i used in example is made for custom classes to implement custom allocators thats why my example looks like total mismatch between two different conceptions?

Comment: @hgrev `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `insert`, `emplace` and `resize` can all add elements

Comment: yes, of course, big thanks for helping me with this question

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` owns the allocator that it uses.  When you use `vector<int> iVec(alloc);`, `alloc` is copied and `iVec` uses that copy of `alloc` to do its allocations.

If you want to modify the contents of the vector, you need to use its interface to do so, like using `iVec.push_back(1)` to potentially allocate space and insert the value into the vector.